# ¿Cómo listo los contactos cuando tienen el mismo apellido?

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo listar varios contactos con el mismo apellido. He creado una agenda en Java, y cuando agrego varios contactos con el mismo apellido no hay ningún problema, pero cuando le doy a la opción de que me enseñe los contactos que tienen el mismo apellido, solo me muestra uno.
Aquí parte del código:

(EN LA CLASE MAIN)-->

```java
private static void buscarContactoApellidos() 
    {
        System.out.println("Indique el apellido del contacto a buscar.");
        System.out.print("Apellido: ");
        String apellidos = pedirApellidos();
        Contacto buscar = agenda.obtenerContactoApellidos(apellidos);
        
        if (buscar != null) 
        {
            System.out.println("Datos del Contacto:\n");
            System.out.println(buscar);
        }
    }
        
    private static String pedirApellidos() 
    {
        String apellidos = "";
            
        while (!validarApellidos(apellidos)) 
        {
            apellidos = teclado.nextLine();
            if (!validarApellidos(apellidos))
                System.out.print("Este apellido no exixte!. Prueba de nuevo:  ");
        }
        
        return apellidos;
    }
```

En la clase agenda.java -->

```java
public Contacto obtenerContactoApellidos(String apellidos) 
    {
        
        for (Contacto cont: agenda)
            if (cont.getApellidos().equals(apellidos)) 
            {//Encontrado
                return cont; 
            }
    
            
        System.out.println("No existe ningun Contacto con el apellido: " + apellidos);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Te muestra uno porque tienes un `return`. `return` hace exactamente lo que significa, *"volver"*. Es decir, interrumpe la ejecución del bucle y se "vuelve" a donde estabas antes de entrar a ese bucle. Cámbialo por un `System.out.println(cont);` y listo.

Answer (score 0):

viendo el código de tu problema es que no estás devolviendo una lista de contanctos sino un único contacto.Supongo que agenda(agenda.obtenerContactoApellidos(apellidos);) tiene una lista de contactos.

```
public List<Contacto> obtenerContactoApellidos(String apellidos) 
{
  ArrayList<Contacto> contactosEncontrados = new ArrayList();
    
    for (Contacto cont: agenda)
        if (cont.getApellidos().equals(apellidos)) 
        {//Encontrado
            contactosEncontrados.add(cont); 
        }
    if(contactosEncontrados == null || contactosEncontrados.size() == 0)
    {
      System.out.println("No existe ningun Contacto con el apellido: " + apellidos);
    }
   return contactosEncontrados;
```

Luego no te olvides que en la clase main tienes que cambiar esta línea de código

```
Contacto buscar = agenda.obtenerContactoApellidos(apellidos);
```

Por esto:

```
List<Contacto> buscar = agenda.obtenerContactoApellidos(apellidos);
```

Espero que la respuesta te sirviera de ayuda, un saludo.